# std thread job system aborts when delay of 1 nanosecond is removed during the adding of jobs

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've included the full source of the project which is only about 100 lines.
This is a multithreaded job system that I'm working on for a school assignment, after struggling a few days with this, mostly due to the fact that this is all very new to me (C++ 11 and std thread).

I have a basic understanding of the thread, mutex and condition_variable classes. However the application throws a debug error: `R6010 abort() has been called.` when I remove the 1 nanosecond sleep call during the adding of individual jobs to the pool. By placing mutex locks during the accessing and the getting of the jobs I hoped to resolve the error, futile however.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

float CalcInvSqr(float x){
    return (x);
}

class ThreadPool{
public:
    ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int numThreads){
        for(int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
            threads.push_back(thread(&ThreadPool::StartThread, this));
        }
    };

    ThreadPool::~ThreadPool(){
        CleanUp();
    }

    template<typename F>
    future<F> AddJob(std::packaged_task<F()>& job) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(poolMutex);
        this->jobList.push([&job]() {
            job();
        });

        this->cv.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
        return job.get_future();
    }

    void StartThread(){
        while(true){

            unique_lock<mutex> uLock(poolMutex);
            cv.wait(uLock);

            if(stopped.load())
                return;

            std::function<void()> f;
            f = jobList.front();
            jobList.pop();

            uLock.unlock();
            f();
        }
    }

    void CleanUp(){
        stopped.store(true);
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(poolMutex);
            cv.notify_all();
            lock.unlock();

            for(int i=0;i<threads.size();i++){
                if(threads[i].joinable())
                    threads[i].join();
            }

            cout<<jobList.size()<<endl;
        }
    }


private:
    mutable std::queue<std::function<void()>> jobList;
    atomic<bool> stopped;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::mutex poolMutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
};

#define JOBS 50

int main(){

    ThreadPool pool(4);

    std::vector<std::future<float>> results;
    for(int i=0;i<JOBS;i++){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
        float num = (float)(rand()%RAND_MAX)/(float)RAND_MAX;
        std::packaged_task<float()> task([num](){
            return CalcInvSqr(num);
        });
        results.push_back(pool.AddJob<float>(task));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<JOBS;i++){
        cout<<"VALUE: "<<results[i].get()<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Jobs Done ! "<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I've hit a roadblock here and can't seem to resolve the error, I hope someone with more experience on this subject could steer me into the right direction.

The code executes successfully and with correct output when the 1 nanosec delay is called.

Comment: FYI I can reproduce this pretty easily on my system. +1 for a complete compilable example. The solution, though...

Comment: In `AddJob`, you capture a reference to `job`. The caller does not keep that object (`task`) alive until the job is complete, indeed it destroys it immediately after `AddJob` returns. This is the source of your undefined behavior.

Comment: You don't need to be holding the lock to call notify (and in fact you shouldn't - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one).

Comment: Condition variables can wake up spuriously, i.e., even when not notified. You should guard the `wait` in `StartThread` with a predicate check: `while (jobList.empty() && !stopped) cv.wait(uLock);`

Comment: You need to initialize `stopped` to `false`. The default constructors of `std::atomic<foo>` do nothing. Yes, I know that Microsoft's implementation value-initializes, but it's not supposed to do so and relying on it is non-portable.

Comment: Oh my gosh, a really good question (finally). +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected program.
Note that the mutex is unlocked before the condition variable is notified. This is important.

You'll notice that I used a shared_ptr in ThreadPool::Add<>. This is because the code is written for c++11. If it were c++14 we could do away with the shared_ptr and simply move the packaged_task into the lambda having first taken the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

float CalcInvSqr(float x){
    return (x);
}

class ThreadPool{
public:
    ThreadPool(int numThreads){
        for(int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
            threads.push_back(thread(&ThreadPool::StartThread, this));
        }
    };

    ~ThreadPool(){
        CleanUp();
    }

    template<typename F>
    std::future<F> AddJob(std::packaged_task<F()> job)
    {
        auto job_ptr = make_shared<std::packaged_task<F()>>(move(job));

        unique_lock<mutex> lock(_job_mutex);

        jobList.push_back([job_ptr]() {
            job_ptr->operator()();
        });
        lock.unlock();
        _jobs_available.notify_one();
        return job_ptr->get_future();
    }

    void StartThread(){
        while (true) {
            unique_lock<mutex> job_lock(_job_mutex);
            _jobs_available.wait(job_lock, [this]() { return !stopped && !jobList.empty(); });
            if (stopped)
                return;
            auto job = move(jobList.front());
            jobList.pop_front();
            job_lock.unlock();
            job();
        }
    }

    void CleanUp(){
        unique_lock<mutex> job_lock(_job_mutex);
        stopped = true;
        jobList.clear();
        job_lock.unlock();
        _jobs_available.notify_all();

        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            if (thread.joinable())
                thread.join();
        }
    }


private:
    std::mutex _job_mutex;
    std::condition_variable _jobs_available;

    std::deque<std::function<void()>> jobList;
    atomic<bool> stopped;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

#define JOBS 5000

int main(){

    ThreadPool pool(40);

    std::vector<std::future<float>> results;
    for(int i=0;i<JOBS;i++){
        float num = (float)(rand()%RAND_MAX)/(float)RAND_MAX;
        std::packaged_task<float()> task([num](){
            return CalcInvSqr(num);
        });
        results.push_back(pool.AddJob<float>(move(task)));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<JOBS;i++){
        cout<<"VALUE: "<<results[i].get()<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Jobs Done ! "<<endl;
    //    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze what happens with a function object you want a thread to call. Step by step:

1. In `main()`, `std::packaged_task<float()> task` is initialized with a function value
2. The `task` is passed by reference to `AddJob()`
3. Inside `AddJob()`, the task is passed by a reference to a lambda function
4. The lambda function holding the reference is stored in a `ThreadPool` object for later evaluation by a thread
5. `AddJob()` returns a future which is then pushed to `results` vector
6. After the push is done, the loop block ends and `task` is destroyed.

If a thread didn't handle the function inside `task` in the short period between pushing it to the `ThreadPool::jobList` and destruction of the `task` object, then a function saved in `jobList` will be left with a reference to invalid memory, as the function object inside `task` was destroyed along with its parent object. A thread calling the referenced - no longer existing - function fails, causing software abort.

Because `std::packaged_task` isn't copyable, you probably want to move `task`'s contents and store it inside your `ThreadPool` object.

Also, just FYI, the additional delay didn't help on my Linux machine.

---

#### Example

I modified a couple of your methods to store `packaged_task`s in `ThreadPool` objects. Because content of `packaged_task` is stored and moved around by value, it is only destroyed after a thread has handled it. Note the use of `emplace` and `std::move` in `AddJob()`.

```
template<typename F>
future<F> AddJob(std::packaged_task<F()>& job) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(poolMutex);
    auto future = job.get_future();
    this->jobList.emplace(std::move(job));

    this->cv.notify_one();
    lock.unlock();

    return future;
}

void StartThread(){
    while(true){

        unique_lock<mutex> uLock(poolMutex);
        cv.wait(uLock);

        if(stopped.load())
            return;

        auto f = std::move(jobList.front());
        jobList.pop();

        uLock.unlock();
        f();
    }
}

mutable std::queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> jobList;
```

---

Also, as mentioned by @Casey in the comments, you should initialize `ThreadPool::stopped` and consider guarding your code agains spurious wakeups. On my system, `stopped` evaluated to true so no threads were up doing their jobs.